# Unable to launch Flutter project in a Dart-only workspace

Tags: flutter

[image: Error Screenshot]

I tried to run my flutter code and got this error message.
Unable to launch Flutter project in a Dart-only workspace. Please open a folder closer to your Flutter project root or increase the value of the "dart.projectSearchDepth" setting.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Try This]

I went to the 'Extensions' section and searched for Dart and Flutter plugins. Then clicked the 'Switch to Pre-Release Version' and error was gone after running the code again.